# Predelivery of WMDRM licenses

Tags: c#, drm

I’ve been asked to create a desktop app (c#) that predelivers a WM DRM license and then plays a live stream using an embedded Windows Media Player instance. All of the examples that I can find of performing license predelivery seem to be using web pages containing an object called “netobj”. Firstly my question is, is it actually possible to predeliver a license outside of a browser. And secondly, is there any example code showing how to do this?

Any help much appreciated!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about WM DRM, but Microsoft new DRM technology called PlayReady do support predelivery of licenses, even outside the browser if you use the PlayReady PC SDK. Code examples is very hard to get your hands on since they only give out the SDK Documentation to licensees, and the licenses is quite expensive.

As I said, I'm not sure if WM DRM can handle this scenario, but I believe (with emphasiz on believe), that it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did manage to get this working quite easily after all. All that was need was a COM reference to MSNETOBJLib and a simple call to RMGetLicense.StoreLicence(licence_string). Worked like a dream :)

Comment: Thats great! I suggest that you answer this question your self by posting you solution, and marking the question as solved. Will give you some more rep to ;)